# temporary storage without using database in C#

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I have this code wherein i compute the total coins inserted to the piggy bank

```
 private void computeTotal()
        {
            tenpesos = (int)tenpeso.Value * 10;
            fivepesos = (int)fivepeso.Value * 5;
            onepesos = (int)onepeso.Value * 1;
            twofivecents = (int)twofivecent.Value * .25;
            tencents = (int)tencent.Value * .10;
            fivecents = (int)fivecent.Value * .05;

            total = tenpesos + fivepesos + onepesos + twofivecents + tencents 
                + fivecents;

            totalText.Text = Convert.ToString(total);

        }
```

what im missing is i want to remember the overall total of my piggy bank as long as the user keeps adding coins or until he closes the application. how can i do this without using the database?

[image]

Comment: Simply use a class (form in this case) level variable.

Comment: @Tim - given that `total`, `tenpesos`, etc, aren't defined in the function, i'm guessing they already are class variables.

Answer (score 4):

Initialize `total = 0;` when the form is constructed and make sure you add to the existing total.

```
total += tenpesos + fivepesos + onepesos + twofivecents + tencents 
            + fivecents;
```

Note the use of the `+=` operator instead of just `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the proper way and make use of a class, which is pretty much designed for your type of problem. Then for each "piggybank" (one person one or more piggybanks.) then you just make more of them like i made one on the top. like so `Piggybank piggybank = new Piggybank()`

then you just increase the content with `+=` then you can make a "read only" type of Total. by just using the get

```
class Program
{
    Piggybank piggybank = new Piggybank();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        piggybank.TenPesos += (int)tenpeso.Value * 10;
        piggybank.FivePesos += (int)fivepeso.Value * 5;
        piggybank.OnePesos += (int)onepeso.Value * 1;
        piggybank.TwoFiveCents += (int)twofivecent.Value * .25;
        piggybank.TenCents += (int)tencent.Value * .10;
        piggybank.FivePesos += (int)fivecent.Value * .05;
    }
}
public class Piggybank
{
    public int TenPesos;
    public int FivePesos;
    public int OnePesos;
    public int TenCents;
    public int TwoFiveCents;
    public int FiveCents;

    public int Total
    {
        get { return TenPesos + FivePesos + OnePesos + TwoFiveCents + TenCents + FiveCents; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it in a simple file, because if you keep it in memory, if your app crashes or your computer goes down, you will lose data.

Here you go, *(TESTED CODE)*

```
public class FileRepository
{
    public FileRepository()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(FilePath, string.Empty);
        }
    }

    public decimal CurrentTotal()
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(FilePath);
        var lastValue = lines.LastOrDefault();
        return decimal.Parse(lastValue ?? "0");
    }

    public void AddMoney(decimal amount)
    {
        var newTotal = CurrentTotal() + amount;
        File.AppendAllLines(FilePath, new[] { newTotal.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });
    }

    protected static readonly string FilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "storage.txt");
}
```

And let's use it,

```
var fileRepository = new FileRepository();
fileRepository.AddMoney(90);
var currentTotal = fileRepository.CurrentTotal();
Assert.AreEqual(currentTotal, 90);

fileRepository.AddMoney(25);
currentTotal = fileRepository.CurrentTotal();
Assert.AreEqual(currentTotal, 115);
```

In your code, it'll be something like:

```
private void computeTotal()
{
    tenpesos = (int)tenpeso.Value * 10;
    fivepesos = (int)fivepeso.Value * 5;
    onepesos = (int)onepeso.Value * 1;
    twofivecents = (int)twofivecent.Value * .25;
    tencents = (int)tencent.Value * .10;
    fivecents = (int)fivecent.Value * .05;

    total = tenpesos + fivepesos + onepesos + twofivecents + tencents
        + fivecents;

    totalText.Text = Convert.ToString(total);

    var fileRepository = new FileRepository();
    fileRepository.AddMoney((decimal)total);
}
```

Next, you may evolve this by adding thread safety and adding logs also, maybe you wanna keep when how much added into bank...

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare global variables in the top of your class

```
public class Class
{
    private int  _total;
    public void computeTotal()
    {
        // Additions
        _total =  total;
    }

    public int GetTotal()
   {
       return _total;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are trying to resolve is rather simple, and it pertains to the core programming concept of [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).  The variable `total` is declared within the scope of the method `computeTotal()`, as such when the method is finished executing the variable is no longer in memory and available.  Instead, you would want to move this variable outside the scope of the method so that it will live on in memory beyond the method's scope.  Once in the correct scope you can use `+=` which will effectively take the method's new total and add it to the running total.

```
private int total;

private void computeTotal()
{
    tenpesos = (int)tenpeso.Value * 10;
    fivepesos = (int)fivepeso.Value * 5;
    onepesos = (int)onepeso.Value * 1;
    twofivecents = (int)twofivecent.Value * .25;
    tencents = (int)tencent.Value * .10;
    fivecents = (int)fivecent.Value * .05;

    total += tenpesos + 
             fivepesos + 
             onepesos + 
             twofivecents + 
             tencents + 
             fivecents;

    totalText.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
}
```